# Can this Javascript function be re-written in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a legacy JS function that is integrated with Cold Fusion to output nth number of ID form fields wrapped in if statements.  Sometimes the output is pretty high and seems very redundant and cumbersome.  I'm thinking a for loop would fix this, but not sure the right way to tackle it.  Below is the legacy code from a sample output.  Any help is appreciated:

```
function checkFinalDisposition(){
if (document.getElementById("mrostatus").value == "Completed"){


    var checkfinal = document.getElementById("finaldisposition").value
    if (checkfinal == 'NEGATIVE' || checkfinal == 'NEGATIVE DILUTE'){
        var checkfinalpass = 'Yes'

        if (document.getElementById("id4735721").value != 'NEGATIVE' || document.getElementById("id4735721").value != 'NEGATIVE DILUTE'){
            var checkfinalpass = 'No'
        }
        if (document.getElementById("id4735722").value != 'NEGATIVE' || document.getElementById("id4735722").value != 'NEGATIVE DILUTE'){
            var checkfinalpass = 'No'
        }
        if (document.getElementById("id4735723").value != 'NEGATIVE' || document.getElementById("id4735723").value != 'NEGATIVE DILUTE'){
            var checkfinalpass = 'No'
        }
        if (document.getElementById("id4735724").value != 'NEGATIVE' || document.getElementById("id4735724").value != 'NEGATIVE DILUTE'){
            var checkfinalpass = 'No'
        }
        if (document.getElementById("id4735725").value != 'NEGATIVE' || document.getElementById("id4735725").value != 'NEGATIVE DILUTE'){
            var checkfinalpass = 'No'
        }
        if (document.getElementById("id4735726").value != 'NEGATIVE' || document.getElementById("id4735726").value != 'NEGATIVE DILUTE'){
            var checkfinalpass = 'No'
        }
        if (document.getElementById("id4735727").value != 'NEGATIVE' || document.getElementById("id4735727").value != 'NEGATIVE DILUTE'){
            var checkfinalpass = 'No'
        }
    }
    else{
        var checkfinalpass = 'No'
        //Multiple IF's from drug query

        if (document.getElementById("id4735721").value == checkfinal){
            var checkfinalpass = 'Yes'
        }

        if (document.getElementById("id4735722").value == checkfinal){
            var checkfinalpass = 'Yes'
        }

        if (document.getElementById("id4735723").value == checkfinal){
            var checkfinalpass = 'Yes'
        }

        if (document.getElementById("id4735724").value == checkfinal){
            var checkfinalpass = 'Yes'
        }

        if (document.getElementById("id4735725").value == checkfinal){
            var checkfinalpass = 'Yes'
        }

        if (document.getElementById("id4735726").value == checkfinal){
            var checkfinalpass = 'Yes'
        }

        if (document.getElementById("id4735727").value == checkfinal){
            var checkfinalpass = 'Yes'
        }

    }

    if (checkfinalpass != 'Yes'){
        var inputfinaldisposition = 'NEGATIVE'
        //Multiple IF's from drug query

        if (document.getElementById("id4735721").value == ""){
            document.getElementById("id4735721").value = "POSITIVE";
        }
        if ((inputfinaldisposition == 'NEGATIVE' || inputfinaldisposition == 'NEGATIVE DILUTE') && (document.getElementById("id4735721").value != 'NEGATIVE' || document.getElementById("id4735721").value != 'NEGATIVE DILUTE')){
        var inputfinaldisposition = document.getElementById("id4735721").value
        }

        if (document.getElementById("id4735722").value == ""){
            document.getElementById("id4735722").value = "POSITIVE";
        }
        if ((inputfinaldisposition == 'NEGATIVE' || inputfinaldisposition == 'NEGATIVE DILUTE') && (document.getElementById("id4735722").value != 'NEGATIVE' || document.getElementById("id4735722").value != 'NEGATIVE DILUTE')){
        var inputfinaldisposition = document.getElementById("id4735722").value
        }

        if (document.getElementById("id4735723").value == ""){
            document.getElementById("id4735723").value = "NEGATIVE";
        }
        if ((inputfinaldisposition == 'NEGATIVE' || inputfinaldisposition == 'NEGATIVE DILUTE') && (document.getElementById("id4735723").value != 'NEGATIVE' || document.getElementById("id4735723").value != 'NEGATIVE DILUTE')){
        var inputfinaldisposition = document.getElementById("id4735723").value
        }

        if (document.getElementById("id4735724").value == ""){
            document.getElementById("id4735724").value = "NEGATIVE";
        }
        if ((inputfinaldisposition == 'NEGATIVE' || inputfinaldisposition == 'NEGATIVE DILUTE') && (document.getElementById("id4735724").value != 'NEGATIVE' || document.getElementById("id4735724").value != 'NEGATIVE DILUTE')){
        var inputfinaldisposition = document.getElementById("id4735724").value
        }

        if (document.getElementById("id4735725").value == ""){
            document.getElementById("id4735725").value = "NEGATIVE";
        }
        if ((inputfinaldisposition == 'NEGATIVE' || inputfinaldisposition == 'NEGATIVE DILUTE') && (document.getElementById("id4735725").value != 'NEGATIVE' || document.getElementById("id4735725").value != 'NEGATIVE DILUTE')){
        var inputfinaldisposition = document.getElementById("id4735725").value
        }

        if (document.getElementById("id4735726").value == ""){
            document.getElementById("id4735726").value = "NEGATIVE";
        }
        if ((inputfinaldisposition == 'NEGATIVE' || inputfinaldisposition == 'NEGATIVE DILUTE') && (document.getElementById("id4735726").value != 'NEGATIVE' || document.getElementById("id4735726").value != 'NEGATIVE DILUTE')){
        var inputfinaldisposition = document.getElementById("id4735726").value
        }

        if (document.getElementById("id4735727").value == ""){
            document.getElementById("id4735727").value = "NEGATIVE";
        }
        if ((inputfinaldisposition == 'NEGATIVE' || inputfinaldisposition == 'NEGATIVE DILUTE') && (document.getElementById("id4735727").value != 'NEGATIVE' || document.getElementById("id4735727").value != 'NEGATIVE DILUTE')){
        var inputfinaldisposition = document.getElementById("id4735727").value
        }

        var answer = confirm("Please advise the Final Disposition does not match your individual results!\n\nPress \"OK\" to change Final Disposition to "+inputfinaldisposition)

        if (answer){
            document.getElementById("finaldisposition").value = inputfinaldisposition;
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: [*What have you tried?*](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: jQuery IS JavaScript. However, you could potentially shorten some of the code using jQuery or even plain old javascript functions.

Comment: To answer the question: Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have a js array of ids you are checking for,

```
idToCheck = ['id4735721', 'id4735722', ...];
```

Then compare them in a for loop.

```
for(id in idToCheck){
      if($('#'+idToCheck[id]).val() != 'NEGATIVE' || if($('#'+idToCheck[id]).val() != 'NEGATIVE DILUTE'){
            checkfinalpass = 'No';
      }
}
```

I didn't redo your whole code but hopefully this will point you in the right direction.

Comment: *"js object of ids"* that's actually an array, but yes this would shorten it and make it more maintainable.

Comment: you are right, will fix that